# Module 'apple_sign_in' not found

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in

I am using flutter with https://pub.dev/packages/apple_sign_in package for logging in with apple.

I was able to publish the earlier version of app with `apple_sign_in` but now I am not being able to archive the Xcode Project for publishing.

Note: I can still build the app and app runs but It does  build when archiving.and throws the error saying

> Module 'apple_sign_in' not found
>   [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was because I came to delete the `Podfile` and regenerate it. **That had generated a lower version of iOS** than that needed by `apple_sign_in` module **as minimum supported iOS version**.

Once I updated the minimum supported iOS version to the minimum required by `apple_sign_in` plugin, the problem was resolved.

As of  `apple_sign_in: ^0.1.0.` we can use `platform :ios, '10.0'`

Comment: I have set ios target version to 10.0, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @RajaC same here, posted the fix I found below.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you're opening xcode from the `Runner.xcworkspace` and not the `Runner.xcodeproj`. cocoapods requires you to archive/build from this entry point. In the flutter docs they mention this but its easy to forget/overlook as the files are so similarly named and used.

Comment: when I try to open the workspace it defaults to xcodeproj

Comment: @krumpli In XCode `File` > `Close Workspace` > Select `Runner.xcworkspace` from your flutter project's /ios folder

Comment: This was the answer for me, thanks. Any idea why this is this case?

Comment: As far as I know, everything is designed around the specific Runner.xcworkspace workspace and file paths within. Runner.xcworkspace has different file paths which results in errors.