# import Module 'app_settings' not found

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

[image: Bug image on XCode]

I have been trying to solve this bug from two days.

It's already been asked before but not a single solution worked for me.

1. [Module 'apple_sign_in' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60575077/module-apple-sign-in-not-found)
2. [importing "Module 'app_settings'" not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66227407/importing-module-app-settings-not-found)

I have already all solutions from above links.

In the end, I even deleted my ios folder and made it again using "flutter create -i swift ." command but still this issue exists

Answer (score 0):

Okay i solved it by deleting and re-creating the IOS Folder by command "flutter create -i swift . " But as I have told in my question that recreating didn't help. What i actually didn't do was to upgrade my IOS deployment target to more recent ones.

I upgraded from 11.0 to 12.0 but that didn't work until I upgraded it to 15.0 in the Podfile and then ran commands like "pod install --repo-update" it worked.

Note: if you face similar issue and if your project can't find RunnerTest by showing error "Unable to find a target named `RunnerTests` in project `Runner.xcodeproj`" then recreating the IOS folder will automatically create this folder.